# Invalid white space character (0x8) in text to output

Tags: soap

While i am getting response in through soap, i am getting this exception for some time. please help in finding the solution. 
Pasting the whole soap response below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Invalid white space character (0x8) in text to output</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail />
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you Googled the error message?

Comment: yes i do, but i am not getting any proper solution for avoiding this exception